# Subsetting using which()

Tags: r

When I execute the code below, some elements in disagreement with the rules remain in the data frame:

```
coefs.total.b <- coefs.total[-which(coefs.total[1:1000, 25:36] < 0.001 &
                                    coefs.total[1:1000, 37:48] > 0.6), ]
```

Comment: What exactly are the rules you are trying to express?

Comment: I want to exclude lines containing elements lower than 0.001 in columns 26 to 36 and elements higher than 0.6 in columns 37:48

Comment: So if in the first row column 26 is < 0.001 and column 38 is > 0.6, do you want to remove the first row or the 1001th? First one seems useful more often, second one is what I think your code does

Comment: If in the first row column 26 is < 0.001 and column 38 is > 0.6, i would like to remove the 1st row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which(coefs.total[1:1000, 25:36] < 0.001)` will (assuming coefs.total is a matrix) test each individual cell, moving row by row. In other words, the 26th of the first row will be the 1001th value and so on.

If you want to combine the tests for the different rows, you need to do this explicitly. From your comments, I assume you want to combine them with or. This can be done by using `apply` row-wise with the function `any` (similarly `all` to express and), or by using `rowSums` which I'm going to show:

```
 coefs.total.b <- coefs.total[-which(
    rowSums(coefs.total[1:1000, 25:36] < 0.001) > 0 &
    rowSums(coefs.total[1:1000, 37:48] > 0.6) > 0), ]
```